# Asynchronous update in a class don't work when navigate from another class using UI.getCurrent().navigate

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

when I navigate from one Vaadin GUI class to another Vaadin GUI class which having an asynchronous update on h1 tag, the asynchronous update does not show any changes on UI until I do something in the same view (like clicking inside an edit box in the same view)

This asynchronous update does work only if I directly access to the GUI class interface

```
///navigate from class code
public class WaitForPlayers extends VerticalLayout {

..........................
   UI.getCurrent().navigate(Playboard.class);
}


//navigate to class, with an asynchronous update

 @Push
    public class Playboard extends VerticalLayout
    {  
private H1 timerc;
private FeederThread thread;
        public Playboard() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException{
            generateGUI();
        }

        private void generateGUI() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
            setSizeFull();
            setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER);
            addClassName("main-view");
            H1 header = new H1("Stock Market Simulation - Playboard");
            header.setWidthFull();
            header.setHeight("10%");
            header.getElement().getThemeList().add("dark");

            add(header);

            HorizontalLayout contents = new HorizontalLayout();
            contents.setSizeFull();
            contents.addClassName("content-view");


            VerticalLayout player = new VerticalLayout();
            player.setWidth("25%");
            player.setHeightFull();
            player.addClassName("player-view");

            VerticalLayout playboard = new VerticalLayout();
            playboard.addClassName("playboard-view");
            playboard.setWidth("75%");


            player.setDefaultHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.START);
            Image p1Img = new Image("frontend/icons/userLogo.png","player");
            p1Img.setWidth("150px");
            p1Img.setHeight("150px");

            H4 playerName = new H4("Player");
            H4 totalWorth = new H4("Cash On Hand : ");
            H4 round = new H4("Round :");
            H4 timeR = new H4("Time Remaining");

            timerc = new H1("30s");


            player.add(p1Img,playerName,totalWorth,round,timeR,timerc);

            player.setHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER,timerc);

            player.setHorizontalComponentAlignment(Alignment.CENTER,p1Img);

            contents.add(player,playboard);
            add(contents);

            Tab buy = new Tab("Buy");
            Tab sell = new Tab("Sell");
            Tabs tabs = new Tabs(buy, sell);
            tabs.setFlexGrowForEnclosedTabs(1);

            playboard.add(tabs);

        }


        @Override
        protected void onAttach(AttachEvent attachEvent) {
            // Start the data feed thread
            thread = new FeederThread(attachEvent.getUI(),timerc);
            thread.start();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDetach(DetachEvent detachEvent) {
            thread.interrupt();
            thread = null;
        }

        //Thread
        private static class FeederThread extends Thread {
            private final com.vaadin.flow.component.UI ui;
            private  final  H1 element;

            private int count = 30;


            public FeederThread(com.vaadin.flow.component.UI ui,H1 element) {
                this.ui = ui;
                this.element = element;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (count>0){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        ui.access(()-> {
                            element.setText(String.valueOf(count));

                        });
                        count--;
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: What vaadin version are you using?

Comment: @Dun0523 13.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/5759. As a workaround, you can either have a common parent `layout` for all your `@Route` classes and then put `@Push` on that class. Alternatively, you can enable push programmatically using e.g. `UI.getCurrent().getPushConfiguration().setPushMode(PushMode.AUTOMATIC)`.